# Making an Application Using YOLO

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, yolo

I'm new to YOLO and trying to make car counting application using YOLO. The cars is from video file. Is there any reference? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple places from which I suggest you try to learn:

1) The CNN course from coursera https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks
This course has a good explanation on yolo(There assignment is on car detection as well which can easily be extended to car counting) and the rest of the course is quite nice as well

2)https://towardsdatascience.com/yolo-you-only-look-once-real-time-object-detection-explained-492dc9230006

The article focus on a few implementation details and talks about the papers yolo and yolov2 , and helped me clear a out a few issues i had when i was trying to implement yolo

3)The original paper (although this may be too advanced ): https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640v5.pdf

4)A keras implmentation : https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2

A simple git clone if you wish to simply have the code , although i do not recommend this as it has very little actual learning and is simply a download and use option